# ExtJs - how formatting tbar?

Tags: extjs

Ext.grid.GridPanel - tbar. How to make a line break?
I need to do two tbar row. On the one title that was, on the other, which is below it - the buttons.

Comment: can you post your grid panel configurations?

Comment: ExtJs already contains 'title' property to set the title.

Comment: what version of extjs? specifically 4.x or earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Use a configuration similar to this,

```
dockedItems:[
    {
        xtype:'toolbar',
        items:[{text:'row one button'}]
    },
    {
        xtype:'toolbar',
        items:[{text:'row two button'}]
    }
]
```